Question about proof that at least one of the $a_i$ is larger than $n$.
Let $n > 1$ be an integer, and $k$ the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $n$. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1}$ be $k+1$ positive integers with the property that none of them divide the product of all the others. Prove that at least one of the $a_i$ is larger than $n$.

For each $a_i$ there is (at least) one of its prime factors (let's call one of them) $p_i$ such that the order of $p_i$ in $a_i$ is larger than its order in the product of the other $a_i$'s.
If $i\neq j$ then $p_i\neq p_j$. In fact, if $p_i=p_j=:p$ then $a_i=p^{r_i}b_i$ and $a_j=p^{r_j}b_j$. If $r_i<r_j$ (and symmetrically for $r_i>r_j$) then the order of $p$ in $a_i$ wouldn't be larger than the its order in the product of the other $a_i$'s.
Therefore, there is an injection from $a_i\mapsto p_i$ to the primes not greater than $n$. Contradiction since there are less $p_i$'s (there are $k$ of them) than $a_i$'s (there are $k+1$ of them).

I have a question over the provided proof. Why does the argument work symmetrically for $r_{i} > r_{j}$?

Granted the phrasing is a bit hard to follow, but the logic is clear.  If the chosen "big  prime factor" in $a_i$ matched the chosen big prime factor in $a_j$, then it would not be true that the order of that prime in $a_i$ exceeded the order of that prime in the product of the others.
